# PSA: use this nifty Data Explorer query to see how close you are to Taxonomist badge

Tags: discussion, badges, data-explorer

I haven't seen that query on DataExplorer before (searching for "Taxonomist" in query list).

For your pleasure, I present:

[How close are you to a Taxonomist Badge](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/87763/how-close-are-you-to-a-taxonomist-badge?MinCountOfQuestionsPerBadge=25)

Comment: The SQL is kind of sucky, admittedly

Comment: I already have Taxonomist :(

Comment: @JackBNimble - Why... So... Serious???

Comment: Mine says invalid username. I am valid!

Comment: @OghmaOsiris - oh? Can you put a screenshot and the exact URL you have in the answer? I'll take a look

Comment: oh, I guess I need to put in my User ID number... It says I already have the badge. But I dont.

Comment: @OghmaOsiris - Yes you do, for "voldemort" tag - you can write a big Thank You letter to Slytherincess ;) http://scifi.stackexchange.com/badges/11/taxonomist?userid=1109

Comment: Um... OK, NOW what did I do wrong to deserve a damned downvote? Breathe?

Comment: @DVK Yep, you get a downvote for every breath you take, every move you make...